# change canvas image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

the desired behavior is when the document loads, canvas draws image 0.  when the invisible div is clicked, canvas draws image 1, on mouseup or mouseout, it reverts back to image 0.

I left the css out because I got that working...just need to know what I'm doing wrong with the javascript function.  right now it doesn't display anything, not even the first image.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function imgChange(imagePath)
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            var img=new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            };
            img.src=imagePath; <!-- I THINK THIS IS WRONG?
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="506" height="319"
onload="imgChange('0.gif')" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
            Your browser does not support the canvas element.
            </canvas>



            <div id="button1" onMouseDown="imgChange('1.gif')" onMouseUp="imgChange('0.gif')" onMouseOut="imgChange('0.gif')"></div>
            <div id="key2"></div>




    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is missing an ending block

```
function imgChange(imagePath) {
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            var img=new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            };
            img.src=imagePath;
}
```

The last '}' is missing

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript looks good. But you can't *click* on an invisible `div`. Make the div visible and try.

Be aware of same [origin policy too](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Image path should be in your domain. If you are running in localhost you might need to have a local HTTP server.

Comment: i've been clicking on the invisible div for the last 12 iterations of this problem.  its not set to invisible...it just doesn't have any content.  anyway, trust me the div works, the javascript does not.  the image files are sitting right next to the html doc...no origin issues.  I've done this same exact thing with CSS, now trying to do with canvas.

Comment: What kind of server you are using?

Comment: I see a syntax error, your function doesn't have curly brackets