# Switching JS canvas element with another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm working with a modified face-to-gif - the prototype can be found here: http://bookfeels.herokuapp.com/. Basically, it's an app that uses your webcam to make a GIF.

I'm trying to simplify the UI, so I want the canvas that's recording to fade out and be replaced by the generated GIF, then fade back in again if the user wants to re-record. The two elements I'm working with are here:

```
facetogif.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
facetogif.gifContainer = document.getElementById('gifs-go-here');
```

So, I want the facetogif.canvas to fade out, and be replaced by the facetogif.gifContainer, but I'm new to JS and I'm not sure how to search for this. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

[Here's how to change an image on the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763229/change-canvas-image-with-javascript):

```
function imgChange(imagePath) {
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
              ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };
        img.src=imagePath;
}
```

You mentioned also that you want to fade out an image as well.  I'd say the easiest way to do that is with [jQuery's fadeOut method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733484/simple-jquery-fade-in-fade-out-image).

It might seem a little intimidating, but it honestly isn't much different that from what you're already doing with document.createElement and such.