# How to automate drawing a signature in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<div class="cnvsWrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Draw your signature div>
```

Steps:
I need to select the tool tip and need to draw the signature (using mouse) in selenium webdriver. Can any body help me on this?

Comment: Please, provide the HTML sample with the signature already drawn

Comment: there is no html sample.

Comment: I tried to record the steps using Selenium IDE but the steps are not getting records

Comment: <canvas class="cnvsCanvas" height="143" width="616" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>

Comment: Try replacing the canvas image with js maybe? Here's an example of how to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10763297/1343698

Answer (score 3):

The below code works for sure. The point is, have `ClickAndHold()` method after `ContextClick()`. Put co-ordinates based on your need.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(getDriver());
WebElement canvasElement = getDriver().findElement(objMap.getLocator(Signature));
                
Action signature= builder.contextClick(canvasElement)                       
                       .clickAndHold()
                       .moveToElement(canvasElement,20,-50)
                       .moveByOffset(50, 50)
                       .moveByOffset(80,-50)
                       .moveByOffset(100,50)
                       .release(canvasElement)
                        .build();                       
                signature.perform();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can "draw" using Actions and moveByOffset interactions. But, you won't be able (as far as i know) to draw "sophisticated" stuff.

See this code example:

```
      Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
      Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(signatureWebElement, x, y)  
      //signatureWebElement is the element that holds the signature element you have in the DOM
                .clickAndHold()
                .moveByOffset(dest.x1, dest.y1)
                .moveByOffset(dest.x2, dest.y2)
                .release()
                .build();
            dragAction.perform();
```

Comment: I tried with the above code but  when we draw a button should be enabled. but it is in disable mode only. what ever we have drawn it is unable to find.                                                       below is the code:                                                  Actions actionBuilder=new Actions(driver);          
Action drawOnCanvas=actionBuilder
                    .moveToElement(canvasElement)
                     .clickAndHold()
                  .moveByOffset(100, 50)
                  .release()
                  .build();
drawOnCanvas.perform();

Comment: I didn't exactly understand what you meant by "...when we draw a button should be enabled. but it is in disable mode only.".
Also, drawing canvases requires you to "click and hold" while you drawing. So i think you should add clickAndHold to your builder.

Comment: I also want to know if i want to draw 4 to 5 with different axis, i added to code as  Actions actionBuilder=new Actions(driver);          
Action drawOnCanvas=actionBuilder
          //     .contextClick(canvasElement)
                .moveToElement(canvasElement)
                .clickAndHold()
             .moveByOffset(100, 50)
              .moveByOffset(6,7)
               .moveByOffset(-15,-50)                                  .release()
                .build();
drawOnCanvas.perform();. its not working. can you pls me out.

Comment: You draw with the moveByOffset method. calculate how the moving should be done for your specific test (i would suggest you to use "simple line", or something similar as agreed with client/server developers, for the test purpose, so the drawing won't become a headache).

Comment: When a signature is drawn Apply button will be enable so that we can save the signature. below is the code                                         a class="pull-right clear disabled">Clear/a>

div class="modal-footer signature-footer">
div class="row"">
div class="save-signature-wrapper clearfix col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> /div>
div class="footer-buttons col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
button class="btn pull-right btn-primary apply" type="button">Apply/button>
button class="btn btn-default cancel" type="button">Cancel/button>
/div>
div class="clearfix"/div>.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem which is like drawing 3 points which will create a polygon and the last double click ends the drawing process, code described bellow works fine for me

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of canvas"));

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(element,135,15) //start points x axis and y axis. 
              .click()
              .moveByOffset(200, 60) // 2nd points (x1,y1)
              .click()
              .moveByOffset(100, 70)// 3rd points (x2,y2)
              .doubleClick()
              .build();
    drawAction.perform();
```

Comment: Hi @Kumrun Nahar Keya Thanks for the answer but it is creating a straight line for me. What should be the offsets to create a closed polygon or say a triangle? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you the answer helped .

builder.moveToElement(AgreementSummaryPage.signatureTextArea,135,15) //start points x axis and y axis.
                    .clickAndHold().moveByOffset(165,15).
                            moveByOffset(185,15)

Answer (score 0):

Using appium 1.9.1, the following code worked fine on Android api level 26 AVD device.

```
new TouchAction((MobileDriver)(driver))
    .press(new PointOption<>().withCoordinates(startX, startY))
    .moveTo(new PointOption<>().withCoordinates(endX, endY))
    .moveTo(new PointOption<>().withCoordinates(endX+50, endY+50))
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
         Action signature= builder.moveToElement(element,100,50) 
//start points x axis and y axis. 
                 .clickAndHold()
                   .moveByOffset(150, 50) // 2nd point (x1,y1)
                   .click()
                   .build();
         signature.perform();
```

This will 100% work , if it's not working check the co-ordinates whether it is actually clicking or not. You can use contextclick() instead of clickandHold() or click() methods to check where it is actually getting clicked.
This is working in the website https://www.docsketch.com/online-signature/draw/